# Cannot edit functions.php and any of the website pages anymore on localhost

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I've just installed Wordpress 6.4.3 & MAMP and managed to edit functions.php and saved my changes.

```
Twenty Twenty-Four: Theme Functions (functions.php)
```

When I tried to make more changes to the file, Wordpress started displaying the following error message:

> Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP.

When I try to edit my website pages, I started getting the following error message now:

> Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.

This is what I've added to functions.php successfully and cannot edit it anymore

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
  $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST["name"]);
  $email = sanitize_email($_POST["email"]);
  $message = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST["description"]);

  // Add code to save the form data to the database
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'request_form';
  $data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'description' => $message,
    'submission_time' => current_time('mysql')
  );
  $insert_result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

  if ($insert_result === false) {
    $response = array(
      'success' => false,
      'message' => 'Error saving the form data.',
    );
  } else {
    $response = array(
      'success' => true,
      'message' => 'Form data saved successfully.'
    );
  }

  // Return the JSON response
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
```

What I have done:

- I've checked permissions of the file and gave read and write access to everyone on my localhost.
- Restarted the server
- Moved wordpress to a new folder
- When I changed http to https for wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) under Settings > General and saved the changes, I was redirected to the following address http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/options.php and can see the following:

  **Notice**:  Undefined index: name in 
    **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-
    content/themes/twentytwentyfour/functions.php** on line 
    **209**
    
    **Notice**:  Undefined index: email in 
    **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp- 
    content/themes/twentytwentyfour/functions.php** on line 
    **210**
    
    **Notice**:  Undefined index: description in 
    **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp- 
    content/themes/twentytwentyfour/functions.php** on line 
    **211**
    **WordPress database 
    error:** [Unknown column 'submission_time' in 
    'field list']
  `` INSERT INTO `wp_request_form` 
    (`name`, `email`, `description`, `submission_time`) VALUES 
    ('', '', '', '2024-03-30 
     07:10:51') ``{"success":false,"message":"Error 
    saving the form data."}

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the error message, I've accessed functions.php file in wordpress folder and commented out the last section of my code which is to return JSON response.

After saving the file, I accessed the file on Wordpress and managed to continue editing it!!!!